# How to get complete graph as JSON from NEO4J in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I see apoc.export.json.data but don't see complete working code example..

I imagine the MATCH query would enable you to get any graph:

```
MATCH g=(someNode)-[someRel]-() return g
CALL apoc.export.json.data( g )
```

Then hopefully the APOC would return JSON of all the nodes and edges in the dataset resulting from the query. Expected JSON:

```
{
  nodes:[
    { id:a1a1 , labels:[Something] , prop_a:99 },
    { id:a2a2 , labels:[Something] , prop_a:77 },
    { id:a3a3 , labels:[User] ,      prop_a:33 }
  ],
  edges:[
    { id:a1a1 , labels:[OWNS] , prop_a:99 },
    { id:a2a3 , labels:[OWNS] , prop_a:77 },
    { id:a4a5 , labels:[HAS] ,  prop_a:33 }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Pls give us a sample of your expected result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an APOC, you can create your own output like below;

```
MATCH   g = ()-[]-()  
RETURN {nodes: apoc.coll.flatten(collect(distinct nodes(g))), 
        edges: apoc.coll.flatten(collect(distinct relationships(g))) } as output
```

I used Enterprise edition ver 5.4 so it should work as well.

Sample result:

[image]

Comment: On Neo4j V5 This doesn't seem to work as the example above.

Comment: what is the error or output in V5? I'm using 4.4 version.

Comment: I edited my answer and used Neo4j sandbox which is Ver 5.4

Comment: I'm also using 5.4. If you make a tiny graph and look at JSON result coming from driver everything is doubled. Double the edges and then double the nodes per every node so 4X

Comment: The Neo4J GUI makes it look like a graph being returned but the underlying data coming from the driver is returning array of arrays and array of two nodes for every node

Comment: apoc.coll.toSet(apoc.coll.flatten(collect(nodes(g)))) returns desired output as original example above, but needs apoc

Comment: I used your suggestion and also added DISTINCT nodes(g) to remove duplicates. Thanks.

Comment: Thank You @jose_bacoy.  Indeed it would be nice if APOC was not necessary since it is not available by default in community edition.